# How applicationContext was loaded?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web.xml

The content of web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/krams/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

There is also an `applicationContext.xml` file in `WEB.INF` but it is not present in `web.xml`. How was it loaded?

Comment: ... probably by org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener? Its  very unclear what you're really asking here, why do you care?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the exact location of spring config file and web.xml?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444410/where-is-the-exact-location-of-spring-config-file-and-web-xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ContextLoaderListerner](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.java), [ContextLoader](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoader.java) and [XmlWebApplicationContext](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/support/XmlWebApplicationContext.java) classes are responsible for loading applicationContext.xml.

Please take a look at their source code on git.

You will find that [ContextLoaderListerner](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.java) is extending [ContexLoader](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoader.java).

In the [ContextLoader](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoader.java) documentation, they have mentioned that:

```
 * If not explicitly specified, the context implementation is supposed to use a
 * default location (with XmlWebApplicationContext: "/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml").
```

And this value is mentioned in [XmlWebApplicationContext](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/support/XmlWebApplicationContext.java) as follows (with other constant values if you need them):

```
/** Default config location for the root context */
public static final String DEFAULT_CONFIG_LOCATION = "/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml";

/** Default prefix for building a config location for a namespace */
public static final String DEFAULT_CONFIG_LOCATION_PREFIX = "/WEB-INF/";

/** Default suffix for building a config location for a namespace */
public static final String DEFAULT_CONFIG_LOCATION_SUFFIX = ".xml";
```

And this is a reason why applicationContext.xml file gets loaded though it is not configured in web.xml file. You will need some time to understand all these default configurations (magic) used by Spring.